# php-fpm mod event is slowly on https with server centos 7, php 7.2

Tags: php, ssl, events, https

i have server centos 7, installed php7.2, mod ssl, php-fpm run with mpm event. So after config completed, i tested with cmd 
`ab -k -c 100 -n 2000 http://myweb.com/test.php`
And results:
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.103 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        2
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 2, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      1998
Keep-Alive requests:    1998
Total transferred:      1048596 bytes
HTML transferred:       467752 bytes
Requests per second:    19506.11 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5.127 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.051 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          9987.32 [Kbytes/sec] received
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      4
  66%      5
  75%      6
  80%      7
  90%     10
  95%     11
  98%     14
  99%     15
 100%     27 (longest request)

it's fast but very slowly when i test it with link https

`ab -k -c 100 -n 2000 https://myweb.com/test.php`
The results:
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   3.831 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      460000 bytes
HTML transferred:       58000 bytes
Requests per second:    522.05 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       191.553 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.916 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          117.26 [Kbytes/sec] received
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    182
  66%    191
  75%    199
  80%    207
  90%    228
  95%    247
  98%    266
  99%    285
 100%    328 (longest request)

everything is still ok on my server, i checked error_log but no logs for this issue above, so i dont know the reason and how to fix it, 
i add more case test on server ssl with apache hanlder, it's fast and i think server with FPM/FastCGI is faster server apache handler

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.612 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    1987
Total transferred:      573427 bytes
HTML transferred:       60000 bytes
Requests per second:    3270.41 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       30.577 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.306 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          915.69 [Kbytes/sec] received
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      2
  66%      3
  75%      3
  80%      4
  90%      5
  95%      7
  98%     12
  99%     65
 100%    584 (longest request)

pls help me, thanks

Comment: That's how it is, its normal. Connections made via https is slower than normal http. The data is being encrypted.

Comment: i dont think so, FPM/FastCGI  faster apache handle and i try testing on server https with apache handler, it's fast: 

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.612 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    1987
Total transferred:      573427 bytes
HTML transferred:       60000 bytes
Requests per second:    3270.41 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       30.577 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.306 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          915.69 [Kbytes/sec] received

Answer (score 1):

@unixmiah is correct. The difference is *all* about the ssl - although the actual encryption is not the overhead - its the key negotiation and the configuration of the SSL termination causing issues.

You have posted 3 sets of results above - the first two show the command you used - testing on http and https but you've not provided the command you used for the third.

In the first set of results:

```
 Keep-Alive requests: 1998
```

In the second set of results:

```
 Keep-Alive requests: 0
```

*even though you specified -k (enable keep-alive) on the command line!*

The most likely reason that there are no keep-alive requests is that your webserver is configured to close the connection when it can't determine if the client supports SSL session renegotiation (i.e. MSIE <=6 ). As a consequence you not only have the overhead of a TCP handshake (2.5 rtts) before each request, but you also have a full ssl negotiation (~3-4 rtts) for each request. The quickest way to get your test rig correctly representing interactions by real browsers is to fudge the user-agent sent by ab:

```
ab -k -c 100 -n 2000 \
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" \
https://myweb.com/test.php
```

(I've not tested this - I am assuming that the version of ab you have is capable of handling ssl renegotiation or that the test is sufficiently short that this will not be an issue, and that your webserver does not implement HTTP/2).

The title of your question is very misleading. It makes no difference to the performance of PHP whether the request is sent via HTTP or HTTPS to the webserver - it always arrives in PHP the same way. If you had tested with static content served by the webserver you would have seen the same pattern of performance.

Comment: thanks for advice, i missing cmd in third case but i still run "ab -k -c 100 -n 2000 [link]https://myweb.com/test.php", my server centos 7.5, apache 2.4.6 and in third case, i switch mode apache handler which show server api Apache 2.0 Handler, and when i switch to server FPM/FastCGI, it's slow with your test cmd run with browser above, ignore -k and run ab -c 100 -n 2000 ...:
Requests per second:    498.92 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       200.434 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.004 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          112.06 [Kbytes/sec] received

Comment: ...and that's because you've still not got keepalives working right. If you want ab to behave more realistically then that's what you need to fix. Go look at the config on the SSL termination.

Comment: yes, i think the server limit ssl CCU max about 500 connects, so that is resquest per second in my test about 500. And i searching for config max ssl CCU or etc involve it.... if y have more idea for config it, pls help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@symcbean and this is my ssl file

Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
 VirtualHost *default*:443
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \ nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \ downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \ "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
/VirtualHost
VirtualHost *:443
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/exp.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/exp.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/exp.crt
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web/
FilesMatch .(php|phar)$
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
/FilesMatch
/VirtualHost

Comment: Where, in the above is CCU constrained? This is a setting on your CDN not in your Webster. Your issue is *still* due to the lack of keepalives. But it is an artefact of your testing mechanism. Either go research the components you are using and try different configurations / clients or stop fretting about the results you see from a flawed test rig.

Answer (score 0):

@symcbean thanks, exactly my prob, i dont know why http can run keepalive but https not working keepalive although i config KeepAlive On in my httpd.conf and run same cmd for both:

`ab -k -c 100 -n 2000 -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" http://exp.com/test.php` 
=> above 6000 req per second, 2000 keepalive req

`ab -k -c 100 -n 2000 -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" https://exp.com/test.php` 
=> about 600 req per second, 0 keepalive req 
but when i access real browser with https://example.com, i see response header have: Connection → Keep-Alive and Keep-Alive →timeout=10, max=150 
haha, i'm crazy for it